# How to get a large volume of data at once?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I’m getting a timeout from the database when I execute a query. I presume the problem is due to the large volume of data. I tested the same query in the development environment, and it worked fine.

What can I do to retrieve all the data from the database at once (I need to get it all in one go, I can’t use pagination or something similar)?

Comment: Write a more performant query/add appropriate indexes; change the timeout settings; buy a bigger/faster DB server. I’m guessing your Prod DB has lower timeout settings than Dev to stop people running massive queries and impacting everyone else using the Prod environment

Comment: What is your Db2-server platform? (Z/OS,  i series ,  linux/unix/windows/cloud?   There are unload tools for this purpose.